# How do I pass through text inputted in SweetAlert2 box to a .then method?

Tags: javascript, html, css, firebase, sweetalert2

Right now I am doing the following:

```js
function resetPassword(email) {
    /* The following is for the alert dialog box that is triggered when the user 
    presses forget password! */
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Enter the email address',
        input: 'text',
        inputAttributes: {
            autocapitalize: 'off'
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Send Reset Email',
    }).then((input) => {
        firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
        .then(() => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Email Sent!',
                text: 'Check your email for a reset link!',
                type: 'success',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: error.message,
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
            });
        });
    });
}
```

But it is not working, what am I doing wrong?

My main outcome is to get the email, pass it through to firebase auth api, send the email, then put one more diag box out that says "done" basically. But the input is not coming through. Why is this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The Swal result will be stored in an object with the same name that you define in the passed parameter to the 'then' function, in this case, `input`. The email address is stored in `input.value`. I'd also remove the unnecessary email parameter from the function declaration. This should work:

```
function resetPassword() {
    /* The following is for the alert dialog box that is triggered when the user 
    presses forget password! */
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Enter the email address',
        input: 'text',
        inputAttributes: {
            autocapitalize: 'off'
        },
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Send Reset Email',
    }).then(({value: input}) => {
        firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(input)
        .then(() => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Email Sent!',
                text: 'Check your email for a reset link!',
                type: 'success',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
            });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            Swal.fire({
                title: 'Error!',
                text: error.message,
                type: 'error',
                confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Doesnt work, I get the error: Uncaught (in promise) T {code: "auth/argument-error", message: "sendPasswordResetEmail failed: First argument \"email\" must be a valid string.", a: null}

Comment: Sorry about that! I'm not too familiar with SweetAlert2. I had another look at their documentation and realised that the data is returned as an object, with the input being stored in the value key (`input.value`). I've updated my code and it should now be working.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer @Chris, but after yours not working I then went onto the SA2 docs and found a login page, then heavily modified it to the following:

```js
function resetPassword() {
    /* The following is for the alert dialog box that is triggered when the user 
    presses forget password! */
    
    Swal.fire({
        title: 'Please Enter Your Email Address',
        html: `<input type="text" id="email" class="swal2-input" placeholder="mail@website.com">`,
        confirmButtonText: 'Sign in',
        focusConfirm: false,
        preConfirm: () => {
            const email = Swal.getPopup().querySelector('#email').value
            return { email: email }
        }
    }).then((result) => {
        firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(result.value.email)
    .then(() => {
        Swal.fire({
            icon: 'success',
            title: 'Email Sent!',
            text: 'Check your email for a reset link!',
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Error!',
            text: error.message,
            type: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
        });
    });
});
}
```

Thanks for your help though and the solution which I am posting now did take a long time to make so you are still greatly appreciated.

Have a nice day!